# What is a Truecrypt alternative with deniable encryption for linux?

Tags: linux, truecrypt, opensource

Preferably an alternative that is Free Liberating Open-Source Software/ FLOSS. I would have used Truecrypt, but it has been discontinued.

Comment: If by "deniable encryption" you mean a second encrypted volume that you can pretend doesn't exist, there is none.

Answer (score 1):

TrueCrypt 7.1a has been forked into other projects, such as [VeraCrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Plausible%20Deniability), which just like TrueCrypt offers hidden volumes.

I can't comment on whether to trust TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt or not (since TrueCrypt's sudden discontinuation), but both are open-source so you can figure it out yourself, and there has been an [audit on TrueCrypt](http://istruecryptauditedyet.com/) recently (as of writing).